# Ubuntu launcher search

Tags: ubuntu

I really like the Ubuntu 20.0 launcher. The thing that comes up when pressing "Super" that lets you search for files and applications. But the search seems very limited and often not able to find files in my home directory. This seems odd/wrong because the "Search" box of a Nautilus window does find the files I'm looking for!

How do I add new locations for the launcher to search? Ideally it should index my entire home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Control Center (Settings) go to *Search*. There you can enable/disabled which applications will be searched for:

[image]

Then in *Search Locations* you can configure which paths to search for:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a great reply!